# Is there any documentation describes the way GSOC algorithm (background subtraction) works?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, background-subtraction

I need to track some moving objects so want to use one of background subtraction algorithms implemented in opencv. Saw some [examples](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EILZ4YsI6rU) of how they work and it seems like GSOC is the one I need (the best result for my purposes), but can't find any good explanation of the way it works. [Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dd5/classcv_1_1bgsegm_1_1BackgroundSubtractorGSOC.html#details) says like this:

> Implementation of the different yet better algorithm which is called GSOC, as it was implemented during GSOC and was not originated from any paper.
>
> This algorithm demonstrates better performance on CDNET 2014 dataset compared to other algorithms in OpenCV.

The most informative source was *doc*, but still not enough to change the parameters reasonably:

> @param **mc** Whether to use camera motion
>
> @param **nSamples** Number of samples to maintain at each point of the frame.
>
> @param **replaceRate** Probability of replacing the old sample - how fast the model will update itself.
>
> @param **propagationRate** Probability of propagating to neighbors.
>
> @param **hitsThreshold** How many positives the sample must get before it will be considered as a possible replacement.
>
> @param **alpha** Scale coefficient for threshold.
>
> @param **beta** Bias coefficient for threshold.
>
> @param **blinkingSupressionDecay** Blinking supression decay factor.
>
> @param **blinkingSupressionMultiplier** Blinking supression multiplier.
>
> @param **noiseRemovalThresholdFacBG** Strength of the noise removal for background points.
>
> @param **noiseRemovalThresholdFacFG** Strength of the noise removal for foreground points.

I tried to google, but achieved nothing.

May anybody share some knowledge about the algorithm?

Comment: I'm getting a server error trying to access Google groups currently but I believe this thread is related to the development of this algorithm: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/opencv-gsoc-2017

Comment: Also you can see from the commit history who the author of the code is: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/commit/42b0e13aef0400fcf0e2e334247a99793f242b80#diff-b71848626699e50d8616e5ea979c107f the author includes his email address in the top comments of the `bgfg_gsoc.cpp` file, so you can contact them.

Comment: Just take one day aside to experiment and learn from adjusting the parameters... Anyways your Question is confusing aboutyour need, do you want to learn the algorithm itself (need a maths equation)? or just learn about those settings (need a page from the manual)?