# openCV background subtraction with GSOC

Tags: python, opencv, background-subtraction

im trying to implement the [GSOC background subtractor from openCV.](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dd5/classcv_1_1bgsegm_1_1BackgroundSubtractorGSOC.html#details)

```
fgbg = cv.bgsegm_BackgroundSubtractorGSOC()
fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
```

but this gives me following error:

```
fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'bgsegm_BackgroundSubtractorGSOC' or its derivative)
```

and

```
fgmask = cv.bgsegm_BackgroundSubtractorGSOC.apply(frame)
```

gives me this error:

```
fgmask = cv.bgsegm_BackgroundSubtractorGSOC.apply(frame)
TypeError: descriptor 'apply' requires a 'cv2.bgsegm_BackgroundSubtractorGSOC' object but received a 'numpy.ndarray'
```

The documentation for .apply() says i only need to supply an inputarray (the frame), the output location and the learning rate. Changing `.apply(frame)` to `.apply(frame, output, -1)` does not fix the error

how do i correctly implement a bgsegm_BackgroundSubtractorGSOC object and use it on my image?

[i read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56020919/is-there-any-documentation-describes-the-way-gsoc-algorithm-background-subtract) but it seems i am failing a step before that already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GSOC and the other background subtraction methods (other than MOG2 and KNN) are located [in the extra modules](https://docs.opencv.org/master/) and require the opencv-contrib library to be installed.
Once it is installed, the module can be used by writing:

```
backSub = cv.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorGSOC()
```